# Import only a single field in robomongo while importing a json file in mongoDB

Tags: json, mongodb, import

How to import only **a single field** in Robomongo while importing a JSON file in MongoDB?

I have tried but no queries of deleting the fields works.. so I want to import a single field. Is it possible?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, please show the code you have tried so far. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Thank @FranckGamess I have got a solution to this. I have a new doubt.

I want a combined query suitable for selecting rows where lang = en i.e. language is equal to English and removing the other rows while I convert this file from JSON to CSV.


json2csv -i Downloads/30.json -f id,text,lang -o Downloads/30.csv